# Usage of "had" for an event that happens at later point in past

Tags: past-tense

If two events are happened in past, then had is generally used to the event that happened earlier in time
For example, you can consider the following

> The patient had died before the doctor came .

What is the issue with the usage of had for the event that occured later point of time

> The doctor had came after the death of patient.

Is it just a rule of grammar to follow or does it have any reason for such usage?

Comment: It would be *The doctor had **come** after the death of patient* ("unmarked infinitive" ***come***, not past tense ***came***). But both your examples requires that the "narrative context" is some point in past time ***after*** the arrival of the doctor (because that Past Perfect ***had come*** refers to some point in past time ***earlier*** than the doctor's arrival). In short, both of your examples are valid ***with Simple Past OR Past Perfect*** - which is appropriate depends entirely on the context. But as a general principle, if you don't know why you want Past Perfect, ***don't use it***

Comment: I want to further expand on the answer by stating that the past perfect tense consists of **had** followed by the past participle form of a verb. The past particle of **come** is **come**. That is the reason **had come** is used instead of **had came** in the second sentence. The past participle of **die** is **died** so **had died** is used in the first sentence. In the case of **arrive**, you use **had arrived** since the past participle of **arrive** is arrived. I hope it helps.

Comment: It helps a lot @SyedDanishAnwar, in fact the 'unmarked infinitive' and the past participle of **come** are identical. Hence Fumble Fingers confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> If two events are happened in past, then had is generally used to the event that happened earlier in time.

This is not generally true.

> I went to the shops in the morning and I ate lunch at Greggs in the afternoon.

Two events, recorded in order. No "had" is needed.

Now in your example it is possible to use the past perfect in the first case.  We can use the past perfect to talk about the state in the past resulting from events that occurred earlier.

> The patient had died...

At the time we are talking about the patient was in a "dead" state, which was a result of the earlier event, them dying.

It would also be completely correct to say

> The patient died before the doctor arrived.

Here we just mention two events in the past.

Now there is an error in your grammar in the second example.  The past perfect is "had come" because the past particle of "come" is "come". The past tense is "came".  Come is an irregular verb.

So

> The doctor had come...

means that "at the time we are talking about, the doctor was already there, as a result of coming earlier"

That is correct, normally the next part would tell us what happened at the time we are talking about, but your example tells us something that happened even earlier, which is confusing.  You are talking about some events in the past, but it seems that all the events occurred before the time that we are talking about... very odd.

So every time you want to use the past perfect "had done something". Ask yourself "is it really necessary".  It is the rarest of English tenses.  Less than one percent of sentences use the past perfect. You don't need to use it every time something happens before something else.

What you write can work, but it is confusing see below for a confusing example, or ignore if you want to.

You can make it work, but you need a whole story to justify it:

> When I arrived at Mary's house, it was in mourning. Frank was dead. Mary was in the kitchen being consoled by her sister. A doctor was writing notes. The doctor had arrived some time after the death of Frank and now he was filling in the paperwork for the mortuary as the exact time of death wasn't known.

(the time of the story is "when I arrived at Mary's house". The doctor came before that, but after the death of Frank.)